# 'sudo' command is broken

Tags: installation, upgrade, sudo

I updated an old centrino-notebook after Ubuntu 9.10 with 12.04 - now
`sudo` seem to be broken, because after `sudo <whatever>` I get the error message:

```
sudo: unable to initialize PAM: No such file or directory
```

In `/var/log` there seem to be no `pam*.log` file any more.

I cannot use `sudo` command for to change permissions of `/etc` files.

Comment: I don't recognise `pam*.log`, but try `/var/log/auth.log` for more information on what's going on.  It looks like some PAM package or other has failed to upgrade; the best way to fix this will involve booting in single-user mode.

Comment: update the result > ls /etc/pam.d/

Comment: You may have to do a password recovery....   If this was a fresh install of 12.04, you might want to try again.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` and copy paste the following lines in it

```
 pkexec nano /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
```

Copy & Paste the following lines

```
 session        [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
 session        requisite                       pam_deny.so
 session        required                        pam_permit.so
 session        required                        pam_unix.so
```

Save & Exit

[Source](http://www.battestini.net/blog/2011/11/21/quick-solution-for-sudo-issue-with-missing-pam-configuration-file/)

Comment: thanks for quick answer. I knew that in /etc is to create the file common-session-noninteractive but I cannot get into single-user-mode with shift-key ? shift-key is "dead" on this installation ?

Comment: can you login to ubuntu desktop session ? if yes open terminal and type the commands

Comment: /etc - files can be created or modified only as root or as sudo, but I am excluded from sudo ...

Comment: try with pkexec

Comment: pkexec is not installed ...

Comment: apparently package-failure while update from 9.10 to 12.04 - so need simply to reinstall ... but how ?

Comment: boot with live cd and make a file

Comment: true - how comes this lacking thought ... ?  :-P thx.