# Sudo command broken

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I upgraded my dedicated server from ubuntu 11.1 to ubuntu 12.04. After the server upgrade says 'unable to initialize PAM: No such file or directory' when i am going to change the user to sudo. I got [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298239/sudo-command-is-broken) solution  which is saying to make the  `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` file manually.

But this thing cannot be done as i do not have the permission to change the super user. Can any one help on this.

Comment: Try `pkexec dpkg-reconfigure sudo`.

Comment: @Danatela, But it seems pkexec is not installed the system, I cannot install is without the super user permission. It's like a deadlock.

Comment: No, just hold [Shift] during a boot, select recovery mode and drop to a root shell with networking. See the provided link for more detailed instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If the [provided solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) seems too complicated, there is another way:

- Reboot the computer
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the boot
- In the GRUB menu, choose `<your Ubuntu version> - recovery mode
- Select `Remount filesystem read/write`
- Choose `Drop to root shell`
- Enter `nano /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` or `vim /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`

And you can always fix everything by booting from LiveCD/LiveUSB, unless you've encrypted your system.

Comment: And then what? I just exit the file just opened (in the last item of your list)?